# Typing lags on terminal on Ubuntu 22.04 Machine when I run Anydesk

Tags: 22.04, anydesk

I am encountering latency when connecting from my Windows 10 device to an Ubuntu 22.04 machine through AnyDesk. After dedicating considerable time to investigating, I've determined that this problem arises exclusively when connecting from my Windows device to the Ubuntu 22.04 machine. The previous version, Ubuntu 20.04, worked seamlessly. The lag is noticeable even on the Ubuntu machine itself (acting as a server) when I type in the terminal.

In an effort to gather more insights, I established a new machine with Ubuntu 20.04 and tested it using AnyDesk, experiencing no issues. However, upon upgrading it to Ubuntu 22.04, the problem manifested. I conducted a similar trial with TeamViewer and encountered no complications.

Despite extensive troubleshooting, I have been unable to pinpoint the root cause of this problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried switching from Wayland back to X11?